# Finding a item in vector STL C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Suppose, I have a value x=10 and I have a vector named vec. Now, Please look at at the snippet and it would be great if you help me to clear my doubt.

```
if(find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),x)==vec.end())
{ statement; }
```

Now, my question is I am finding x on the vector. If I am able to find the x in this vector than "statement" will be executed. Why I have to write "==vec.end()" there? What is the role of this particular thing?

Comment: That's because [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an iterator and not a boolean value.

Comment: If you find `x` in the vector then it will not be `== vec.end()`, so statement will only execute if `x` is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an *iterator* which refers to the found element or `end()` if it does **not** find the element. So your code is the wrong way round, it should be

```
if(find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),x)!=vec.end())
{ statement; }
```

Your question is why is it like this. Well it's useful to have `find` return an iterator to the found element (instead of just a boolean). Given then that `find` must return an iterator having it return `end()` when it doesn't find anything is logical, since `end()` is an iterator value that does not refer to any element in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

find returns the iterator showing the element, where it found x. If x is not found it will return `vec.end()`, so the logic is just the other way around: statement will be executed, when x is not found.